# trying to get a Django 3.2 app recognized in python 3.9

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I'm trying my hand at Django 3.2.  I installed the app, and followed what I could from the guidance, and I seem to can't to get the app module to be recognized.

Here's my steps to reproduce the problem:

**in terminal**

```
django-admin startproject research
django-admin startapp landing
```

Then I made the following file changes:

**landing\__init__.py**

```
default_app_config = 'landing.apps.LandingConfig'
```

**landing\apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class LandingConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'landing'
```

**landing\models.py** (trying to add stripe in future release)

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class StripeSubscription(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(help_text="The start date of the subscription.")
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, help_text="The status of this subscription.")
    # other data we need about the Subscription from Stripe goes here 


class MyStripeModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    stripe_subscription = models.ForeignKey(StripeSubscription, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

**landing\urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

**landing\views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the landing index.")
```

**settings.py - Installed apps**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'landing.apps.LandingConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles'
]
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('landing/', include('landing.urls')),
]
```

**In Terminal**

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
```

**Response**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sinistersparrow/Documents/projects/research/backend/research/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/sinistersparrow/Documents/projects/research/backend/research/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 212, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'landing'
```

**Tree Structure**

```
.
|____frontend
|____backend
| |____research
| | |____research
| | | |____asgi.py
| | | |______init__.py
| | | |______pycache__
| | | | |______init__.cpython-39.pyc
| | | | |____urls.cpython-39.pyc
| | | | |____wsgi.cpython-39.pyc
| | | | |____settings.cpython-39.pyc
| | | |____settings.py
| | | |____urls.py
| | | |____wsgi.py
| | |____db.sqlite3
| | |____manage.py
| |____landing
| | |____migrations
| | | |______init__.py
| | |____models.py
| | |______init__.py
| | |____apps.py
| | |____admin.py
| | |____tests.py
| | |____urls.py
| | |____views.py
```

What am I missing here?
Thanks!!!

Comment: you have tried only   'landing' in your installed app?

Comment: yes.  same response.  Guidance at DjangoProject (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial02/) is what I'm doing.  however, I did try both.

Comment: try with empty  landing\__init__.py file

Comment: no change.  same response..

Comment: can you print your folder structure? i suspect you run `django-admin startapp landing` in wrong path. You should `cd research` first, then run `django-admin startapp landing`.

Comment: I saved it up in the question at the bottom.  Thanks

Comment: I did a test where I moved landing inside one folder, and it fired right up.  You were right.  please put this in the answer, so I can give you credit.